# RSA key generation

Tags: c, rsa, number-theory

```
//test whether it is prime number ot not   
int prime_test(long int prime_number)

{
      long int a, p;
      srand((unsigned)time(NULL));

      //0 and 1 not meaning for prime test.
      a = rand() % (prime_number - 2) + 2; 
      printf("a -> %li\n", a);

      //Lehmann Algorithm, p = a^((prime_number-1)/2) mod prime_number
      p = (long int)pow(a, (prime_number - 1) / 2) % prime_number;
      printf("p -> %li\n", p);

      if(p != 1 & (prime_number - p) != 1)
      {
                  printf("Enter number is not prime number.\n");
                  return 0;
      }
      else
      {    
                  printf("Enter number is prime number.\n");
                  return 1;
      }
}
```

My question is why I get negtive p -984, actually 1997 is a prime number,
it should be 1 or -1 either.
The output is like following:

Enter the prime number p: 1997
a -> 1557
p -> -984
Number entered is not a prime number!
temp1 -> 0
Pls re-enter the prime number p:

Comment: That is the function used to big prime number test, it works for very small number like 13 and 17, but once I enter big number, it comes out negtive number, so I post here, can someone give me answer?

Comment: `long int` is not nearly enough for what you want. For testing purposes change that to `long long int`. But even that will not be enough for any real use, you'll need to use bigints.

Comment: @mtijanic: the OP's example is a bit too large for bigint, by a factor of about 38 universes.

Comment: @Jongware I just looked at the actual numbers.. Yeah, that's not gonna work. If you want to use Lehmann's algo it would require a very custom int representation, and I doubt it is feasible. Try another algorithm, such as a sieve.

Comment: ye, I do want use the better one to make it works, but the situation is I have to use Lehmann's, so..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1557 ^ 998 doesn't quite fit into a `long int`.

To be a bit more constructive: If you computed `p` like so, it would take longer, but avoid the overflow:

```
p = 1;
for ( i=0; i<(prime_number-1)/2; i++ )
    p = (p*a) % prime_number;
```

There are (very good) ways to optimize that, but I'll leave that as an exercise.

Comment: your idea is very useful, I create a function to simulate the base and power, i.e a^p mod m,  in that function, we could do something like this:

Comment: for(i = 1; i < pow; i++){}

Comment: temp = 1; in for loop, we do temp = (temp * base) % mod; in this way I make my program works. lol

Comment: use that way instead of p = (long int)pow(a, (prime_number - 1) / 2) % prime_number;